# Rails collection render cache doesn't work when I use cached: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

My project is with Rails 4.2.9.

I found out that the cache doesn't work in the index pages. (I checked with the log.)

```
# This doens't cache.
<%= render partial: 'docs/doc', collection: @docs, cached: true %>

# This caches fine.
<% @docs.each do |doc| %>
  <% cache doc do %>
    <%= render 'docs/doc', doc: doc %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

According to the rails guide, the first example not only works but also is better. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's the link. See 1.3.1:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're going to need to update your version of rails, to at least version 5, for this to work.

It looks like [version 5 has this feature](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/caching_with_rails.html#collection-caching), but [version 4.2 does not have this feature](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching). It was added in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23695) and you can read more about it at https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/09/rails-5-makes-partial-redering-from-cache-substantially-faster.html.